# Implementation of Heap from Scratch

Tags: python-3.x, heap

I am trying to implement Heap Data Structure with scratch. Could someone give me a pseudo code for the same?

I am trying to make each node with 4 variables. 1st Variable is for data, a 2nd variable is for parent node and the last two variables are for child nodes. I know that in theory the nodes are added from left to right but how does one implement the same. As of now, I am stuck at add function.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data,parent=None,child1=None,child2=None):
        self.data=data
        self.parent=parent
        self.child1=child1
        self.child2=child2

class Heap:

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        self.parent=parent


    def add(self,data):

        new_node= Node(self,data,parent=None,child1=None,child2=None)
        new_node.parent=self.parent
        if self.parent is not none:
            if self.parent.child1 is None:
                self.parent.child1=new_node
            if self.parent.child2 is None:
                self.parent.child2=new_node
                #update self.parent=new_node??
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules for inserting into a min heap:

```
add new item to the end of the array
while the new item is larger than its parent
    swap the new item with its parent
```

The rules for removing the top item in the heap (i.e. the smallest)

```
save the top item
move the last item in the array to the first position
while the item is larger than either of its children
    swap the item with its smallest child
```